# Remove function in text editor, leave parameter

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

I'm updating old code from a project and it has thousands of old php mysql_real_escape_string() calls.

The problem is I can't do a search replace because I need to keep the parameter in the () and then remove the closing ) from the call. Is this possible to do in an editor like sublime or vscode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific problem (I'm using Sublime Text 3)

Sample string:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(parameter)
```

Find pattern (note we need to escape the parenthesis of the function):

```
mysql_real_escape_string\((.*?)\)
```

Replace:

```
new_fun(\1)
```

Which will result in:

```
new_fun(parameter)
```

We match the old function, and capture the parameter in group 1. Then replace with the new function, and put the parameter (captured in group 1) inside using `\1`

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/OqOGGX/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups in Sublime Text 3 search and replace. Thus, you can capture the parameter and use the back-reference to refer to it in replaced text.

Capturing groups in regexp use the special parenthesis characters to "capture" matches and make them available in "back-references" `$1`, `$2` etc., which are like variables containing the matched group.

1. Say we have a string:

`SOMETHING_UNWANTEDMY_FIRST_CAPTURED_WORDSOMETHING_UNWANTEDMY_SECOND_CAPTURED_WORDSOMETHING_UNWANTED`

2. **Find** with regex:

`SOMETHING_UNWANTED(MY_FIRST_CAPTURED_WORD)SOMETHING_UNWANTED(MY_SECOND_CAPTURED_WORD)SOMETHING_UNWANTED`

3. **Replace** using capture groups:

`$1$2`

4. **Result**:

`MY_FIRST_CAPTURED_WORDMY_SECOND_CAPTURED_WORD`